# problerm creating due to *{margin:0 auto} property in every page

Tags: reactjs

*{margin:0 auto}   this property applies automatically on all my react pages and components even when i do not import Css file in which include this property *{margin:0 auto} due to this property the alignment in my pages does not work properly

Answer (score 0):

The CSS rule `*{margin:0 auto;}` will affect the entire application, not just the component or file where it is imported because the asterisk `(*)` is known as the CSS `universal selectors`. This selector is useful when we want to select all the elements on the page.

If you want to apply styles only to specific components or elements, you should `avoid using the * selector` and instead apply the styles directly to the specific components or elements you want to style.

Reference Link: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/what-is-the-use-of-asterisk-selector-in-css/

Answer (score 0):

This CSS code `*{margin:0 auto;}` applicable for every react component. `(*)` this is a universal selectors.avoid `(*)` and it will solve your problem.